# Expression Transfer Deep Learning Problem

Tags: deep-learning, generative-adversarial-networks, style-transfer

I have old video and I want to keep the person's face in the video but I want to transfer my facial expressions to that video. Is there any better alternative to first order motion model for that task ? I tried deepfacelab but it has kind of steep learning curve

Comment: What do you mean by "first order motion model"? Maybe you should also show us what you're expecting and what _exactly_ you have tried.

Comment: I was using this: https://github.com/AliaksandrSiarohin/first-order-model